# classic asp - sagepay - token - form method

Tags: forms, asp-classic, integration, token, opayo

I currently have a few sites that use the form method to post basket info to the SagePay system.
I am looking to use the Token system protocol with this method, is it possible? I can't find any documentation on this?
It says to use TxType=TOKEN in the guide but i'm not sure that will work with the form method?
Is it just an extra stage in the form process, currently:
1) Form gathers information (basket and client) and encrypts ready to post to SagePay
2) Posts to SagePay which directs the clients onto the SagePay servers to enter their card details
3) Sagepay posts back to the return URL with the details of the transaction
All done

New Token process:
1) Form initially gathers info for token system (client details)
2) Posts to SagePay token system
3) Sagepay returns info to return URL
4) Form gathers information (basket and client and Token) and encrypts ready to post to SagePay
5) Posts to SagePay which directs the clients onto the SagePay servers to enter their card details
6) Sagepay posts back to the return URL with the details of the transaction

Does that sound correct?
Are there any example(s) available for this type of integration?

Answer (score 0):

Token is available using Server or Direct integration. Not available on Form.

The Token Guide is available via [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/1171/download-document/sagepaytokensystemprotocolandintegrationguidelinev3.0_0.pdf?token=h_CTVw8bhWjZHngM9p-BiaWx4_dkRDp-yEmViMRu6tw) and if you want to refer to the Server or Direct protocols, click [here](http://www.sagepay.co.uk/support/find-document) and select the option you would like.

If you have any other questions, let us know.

Sage Pay Support